# Find the alive people using SPARQL (choose the items that doesn't have an edge)

Tags: rdf, sparql, freebase, dbpedia, virtuoso

Following sparql query will give the persons who are dead.

```
select distinct ?item{
?item <http://freebase.com/ns/common/topic/notable_types> <http://freebase.com/ns/people/person> .
?item <http://freebase.com/ns/people/deceased_person/date_of_death> ?y .
}
```

I want to get all the persons who are alive.
How to express this in SPARQL syntax?
Its more like asking, get me all the nodes which doesn't have a specific edge.
Is it possible in SPARQL?

Thanks in Advance.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can use this construction:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item {
    ?item <http://freebase.com/ns/common/topic/notable_types> <http://freebase.com/ns/people/person> .
    OPTIONAL {?item <http://freebase.com/ns/people/deceased_person/date_of_death> ?y}
    FILTER (!BOUND(?y))
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not give you only people who are alive. It only gives you people who do not have a recorded date of death in freebase.

Answer (score 3):

In SPARQL 1.1

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item {
    ?item <http://freebase.com/ns/common/topic/notable_types> <http://freebase.com/ns/people/person> .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?item <http://freebase.com/ns/people/deceased_person/date_of_death> ?y}
}
```

Comment: This also works! Unfortunately I couldn't accept two answers. So, given an upvote.
Thanks a lot. Where can I find the documentation of all the possible things on SPARQL and SPARQL 1.1 ?
Please point me if there are any nice tutorials.